# Connecting to an Ftp client works for one program but not for the other

Tags: firewall, ftp-client, antivirus, windows-firewall

I have written an application (in Delphi) which connects to an FTP server.

- My application gets timeout error when connecting
- Connecting to the *same Ftp server* with Total Commander with the same credentials works well
- However my application *can* connect to the FTP server on *any other computer* except mine (it even works on a computer which is next to mine, on the same network)

So my application cannot connect to the FTP server only on my computer (or any other FTP connection).

I did this:

- I completely disabled the antivirus software (ESET Internet Security)
- I disabled the Windows firewall

It didn't help.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I wonder if this is a DNS resolution issue? Maybe your ftp server is only listening on the network IP, and Total Commander is trying that IP, while your client is trying localhost?

Comment: Thank you Douglas, I checked it and it didn't solve the problem :-(